# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin project incompatible

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So I'm trying to target iOS 11 via Xamarin for Visual Studio. I upgraded my version of Visual Studio to 2017 (enterprise) (also updated Xamarin on my mac) but when I open the solution it says "(incompatible)" next to each project. The project was originally created with VS2015 and my current version of Vs is 15.3.5. All documents I find is that Xamarin is baked into the new VS2017 version. Can anyone advise?

[image]

Comment: It appears to me you are missing at least the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat` component in your install. (It is an optional component)